# Grayscale Color Depth in Android OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

In OpenGL ES, colors range from 0-1f. Do these values directly map to 0-255, aka 8-bit? Or does the 0-1f range achieve finer colors at higher than 8-bit?

I'm producing a pattern programmatically where rgb are equal (because it's grayscale) so effectively the image is 8-bit. I'd like to achieve a deeper color depth in grayscale such as 16-bit, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your input/output texture format; if it is RGB565 then it's going to be less than 8-bit, if it's RGB10_A2 then it's going to be more than 8-bit.

Texture filtering (e.g. bilinear or trilinear) is generally done at higher precision than the original data, so may result in values which are not exactly e.g. a multiple of 1/256 for an 8-bit texture.

> I'd like to achieve a deeper color depth in grayscale such as 16-bit, is this possible?

OpenGL ES 3.0 has wide integer formats, OpenGL ES ES 3.2 has fp16 and fp32 formats, so it's definitely possible to store relatively arbitrary data at more than 8 bit per channel.

However, the real question is for what purpose? If you intending to show the value on screen then the odds are you have no device actually capable of displaying 16-bit per channel color. Nearly all consumer-grade monitors and mobile device panels are 8-bit per color channel (in mobile, many are not even that and accept 8-bit data but only display 6 or 7 bits of precision in the panel).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I'm doing is programmatically generating a pattern that I'd like to show, and I'd like to achieve really fine differences in contrast. For example, if I have a pattern with max of 250 and min of 248 in rgb grayscale, with values interpolated in between, this is the absolute least contrast I can show with 8-bit resolution. I can vary the brightness to play with it, but ultimately I wanted to have finer control over those values. 

Also, I'm not using bitmaps, I'm passing color data with my vertices straight to the shaders. Does that make a difference?

Comment: You can do some kind of tone mapping - remapping the input color range to something different. Look at some of the HDR tone mapping techniques for ideas; many of the concepts are similar to what you are trying (scaling one luminance range up or down to a different display range). It's not trivial - especially when scaling to increase constrast - you may need some filtering to avoid banding problems. However, at the end of the day you are going to hit the 8-bit limit of the panel you are using.